# Do we really need ID_CAP_NETWORKING for ShellTile in WP apps?

Tags: windows-phone, live-tile, secondary-live-tile

The documentation for the [Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ShellTile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.shell.shelltile(v=vs.105).aspx) class states that we need to specify the ID_CAP_NETWORKING capability in the app manifest. Do we really need it? It's strange that we need to enable networking capabilities for the tile functionality... And my tests on the emulator and real devices confirm that we do not need this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data for tile is coming from any API, for that accessing network **ID_CAP_NETWORKING** Capabilities is needed to Project otherwise its not needed to be added. For Displaying Static data from App There is no need of it. Without it, Static Text or data would be displayed properly.

Comment: If I get you right, if I create a tile (say IconicTile) from my app and specify its title and counter using constants, then we do not need ID_CAP_NETWORKING? We need this capability if the tile data come through a push service or something like this, right?

Comment: yes. for constants it doesn't need but if counter is coming from API, Its needed

Comment: did you get your answer ? If my answer helped you, Please mark as answered so that others can have Reference in future.